# Soft hyphens with priority don't change style with their environment but should do so

Tags: luatex, babel, hyphenation, german, discretionary

Feeding

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%%% The following 3 lines may be uncommented; it doesn't really matter.
%\hyphenpenalty=49% one less than the default value 50.
%\exceptionpenalty=50%%% ad-hoc value greater than \hyphenpenalty.
%\exhyphenpenalty=48%%% ad-hoc value less than \hyphenpenalty (though usually they coincide).
\babelhyphenation[ngerman]{Fuß{-}{}{}[1]gän{-}{}{}[2]ger-am{-}{}{}[2]pel}
\begin{document}\noindent
% Right:
\hspace*{30em}\emph{Fußgängerampel}\\
\hspace*{30em}\textbf{Fußgängerampel}\\
{\Huge
\hspace*{10em}\emph{Fußgängerampel}\\
\hspace*{10em}\textbf{Fußgängerampel}}\\
% Wrong:
\hspace*{31em}\emph{Fußgängerampel}\\
\hspace*{31em}\textbf{Fußgängerampel}\\
{\Huge
\hspace*{11em}\emph{Fußgängerampel}\\
\hspace*{11em}\textbf{Fußgängerampel}}
\end{document}
```

to `lualatex` yields

[image: output]

As you see, the automatically generated hyphens at the line ends have the correct style (upright/italics, normal/bold, size) iff the corresponding hyphenation points are given by the plain `-`.  If a hyphen produced by `{-}{}{}[priority]` is used, it is typeset upright, nonbold, normal size regardless of the environment. This is clearly wrong.

Who is the culprit and what to do?

PS. Off-topic and related: As prioritized hyphenation seems to be still experimental, instead of penalties, say, 50, 52, 104, 156, … for the main, first, second, third, … hyphenation priority, I'd rather have penalties closer together, say, 50, 52, 54, 56, … .  This would be more consistent with the formula \hyphenpenalty + ⋅\exceptionpenaltyincrement (for a fresh variable \exceptionpenaltyincrement) rather than the current ⋅\exceptionpenalty to represent the penalty generated by `{-}{}{}[]`.  So if you dare change the semantics of `{-}{}{}[]`, please feel free.

Comment: Why can't you use `\babelhyphenation[ngerman]{Fuß-gän-ger-am-pel}`? Or `Fuß\-gän\-ger\-am\-pel` in your text, for that matter, it not being a terribly common word?

Comment: it breaks already in plain, e.g. `\hyphenation{hyphen{before}{after}{}ation}
\font\test=cmss10
\hsize=3cm
xxx {\test hyphenation} xxx
\par
xxx \test hyphenation xxx
\bye`

Comment: @ingmar I prefer certain breaks over the other ones. Fußgängerampel is a composite of Fußgänger and Ampel, and Fußgänger is a composite of Fuß and Gänger. So, you prefer to break Fußgänger-ampel, and if it's bad, Fuß-gängerampel, and if this one is bad, all the other possibilities. Hence the priorities.

Comment: Note weighted hyphens have been available for some years through `babel` transforms (besides other non-standard hyphenation rules). See https://latex3.github.io/babel/guides/non-standard-hyphenation-with-luatex.html

Comment: @JavierBezos I'm afraid I don't understand that documentation. How do I actually specify the breaking priorities 0, 1, 2 in *Fußgängerampel* with these babel transforms?  I need the following priorities: *Fuß-1gän-2ger-0am-2pel* (the lower the number, the more likely a break is to occur there). I'm afraid I'm missing such a whole-word example in the documentation.

Comment: @GeekestGeek I will try to prepare a detailed explanation in a few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug at the engine level so not really fixable in babel it is losing the font if the fields in the discretionary are empty as shown by this plain TeX example. The workaround is to ensure the fields are not empty by placing the following character in the "after-break" and "no-break" slots.

```
\hyphenation{hyphen{before}{after}{}ation}
\font\test=cmss10
\hsize=3cm
\hfuzz10pt

{

x hyphenation

x {\test hyphenation} 

xxx {\test hyphenation} xxx

xxx \test hyphenation xxx

}

\bigskip

{

\hyphenation{hyphen{before}{afterat}{at}ion}
\font\test=cmss10
\hsize=3cm
\hfuzz10pt

x hyphenation

x {\test hyphenation} 

xxx {\test hyphenation} xxx

xxx \test hyphenation xxx

}

\bye
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%%% The following 3 lines may be uncommented; it doesn't really matter.
%\hyphenpenalty=49% one less than the default value 50.
%\exceptionpenalty=50%%% ad-hoc value greater than \hyphenpenalty.
%\exhyphenpenalty=48%%% ad-hoc value less than \hyphenpenalty (though usually they coincide).
\babelhyphenation[ngerman]{Fuß{-}{g}{g}[1]än{-}{g}{g}[2]er-am{-}{p}{p}[2]el}
\begin{document}\noindent
% Right:
\hspace*{30em}\emph{Fußgängerampel}\\
\hspace*{30em}\textbf{Fußgängerampel}\\
{\Huge
\hspace*{10em}\emph{Fußgängerampel}\\
\hspace*{10em}\textbf{Fußgängerampel}}\\
% Wrong:
\hspace*{31em}\emph{Fußgängerampel}\\
\hspace*{31em}\textbf{Fußgängerampel}\\
{\Huge
\hspace*{11em}\emph{Fußgängerampel}\\
\hspace*{11em}\textbf{Fußgängerampel}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Could I perhaps ask you to post it to the luatex list (which I'm not a member of)?

Comment: @GeekestGeek https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/dev-luatex/2022-July/006682.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! Perhaps you might wish to reference this TeX.SE-thread there, so that the intended usage is clear to the luatex developers.

Comment: @GeekestGeek latex files don't help Hans:-)

Comment: I tried the suggestion of you (and Ulrike?) and discovered what I believe to be yet another bug: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/652458/discretionary-broken .

Answer (score 0):

This post isn’t an answer (at least directly) to the original question, but to a [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/652328/soft-hyphens-with-priority-dont-change-style-with-their-environment-but-should?noredirect=1#comment1626014_652328). It’s a full answer because the explanation is a bit large and, on the other hand, it provides an alternative way to define ‘ranked’ hyphens in case you need them. Unlike `\babelhyphenation`, which is a wrapper for `\hyphenation`, the procedure explained here was devised for general rules (lua patterns are allowed) and not for specific words, but it can be used for the latter, too, although in some cases the resulting declaration can be somewhat cumbersome.

Here we define a rule to be applied to `ngerman` (the first argument) after the TeX hyphenation pass and the pattern is `Fuß|gän|ger|am|pel`, where `|` stands for a discretionary. If this pattern is matched, then replace the corresponding nodes with those in the third argument, which is a comma-separated list. `{}` means ‘keep the node, do nothing’, while `{ pre=-, penalty=100, data=3}` means ‘replace the current node (in this case a discretionary) by a discretionary with `-` as the `pre` string, a penalty of 100 and with data (eg, font) from the third node. In this case I’ve just taken the font from the previous letter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\babelposthyphenation{ngerman}{ Fuß|gän|ger|am|pel }
 { {}, {}, {},  % Fuß
   { pre=-, penalty=50, data=3 },
   {}, {}, {},  % gän
   { pre=-, penalty=100, data=7  },
   {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, % ger|am
   { pre=-, penalty=100, data=14  },
   {}, {}, {}
 }

\begin{document}\noindent
\hspace*{30em}\emph{Fußgängerampel}\\
\hspace*{30em}\textbf{Fußgängerampel}\\
{\Huge
\hspace*{10em}\emph{Fußgängerampel}\\
\hspace*{10em}\textbf{Fußgängerampel}}\\
\hspace*{31em}\emph{Fußgängerampel}\\
\hspace*{31em}\textbf{Fußgängerampel}\\
{\Huge
\hspace*{11em}\emph{Fußgängerampel}\\
\hspace*{11em}\textbf{Fußgängerampel}}
\end{document}
```

The result is:
[image]

Comment: Thx! By saying `data=13`, you take font information from the 13th symbol in *Fuß|gän|ger|am|pel*, i.e., from *a*, right?

Comment: Moreover, does this approach assume that TeX has already inserted the hyphenation marks at correct places?

Comment: Oops! I meant 14 (fixed), but in this case it doesn’t matter. And yes, it‘s processed after the TeX hyphenation pass.

Comment: Thx! By the way, `\babelposthyphenation` is available only with `lualatex`, and not with any other of [xe|pdf]latex, isn't it? In other words, without `lualatex`, is there any possibility to globally set different priorities for line breaks in a concrete, fixed word? You could of course say `\newcommand{\pedestrianLights}{Fuß\penalty52 gän\penalty54 ger\penalty50 am\penalty54 pel}` in the preamble, but if the user forgets to use `\pedestrianLights` instead of `Fußgängerampel`, the user is doomed as before, isn't he/she/it?

Comment: I was surprised to find out that adding a comment at the start of the second argument, i.e., `\babelposthyphenation{ngerman}{ Fuß|gän|ger|am|pel }{% any comment …`, breaks the behavior. This is strange and probably unwanted.

Comment: Feature suggestion: it would be nice to allow for computing penalty values, e.g.,  `{pre=-, penalty=\hyphenpenalty+1, data=7}`.  Full example: https://pastebin.com/raw/PXdpNxwY (set to expire in 1 year). This is because you might wish to set once for the whole document how eagerly words should be broken. In this case, you wish to adjust only one parameter for this, which has been `\hyphenpenalty` so far.

Comment: Does this interfere with the changes introduced by the package microtype?