# Trying to assign priorities to different breaking points in a word. Discretionary broken?

Tags: luatex, babel, hyphenation, german, discretionary

I try to assign priorities to different breaking points in a word. To this end, I work around the bug [Soft hyphens with priority don't change style with their environment but should do so](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/652328) and follow http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/652386. Feeding `lualatex` with

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\babelhyphenation[ngerman]{Ab{-}{s}{s}[3]{-}{t}{t}[2]rak{-}{t}{t}[1]i{-}{o}{o}[2]ns-ebe{-}{n}{n}[2]e}
\begin{document}
\hspace*{30em}Abstraktionsebene
\end{document}
```

results in an output where `i` is replaced with `t`:

[image: German-example output]

This replacement of *i* with *t* is clearly wrong. Moreover, the correct hyphenation points are *Abs-trak-ti-ons-ebe-ne* according to http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Abstraktion and http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Ebene . So, *Abstrakt-ionsebene* would also be wrong.

The above example is real-life. A slightly smaller one (and NOT real-life because the break points are NOT grammatical below) is

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\hyphenation{ab{-}{s}{s}[3]{-}{t}{t}[2]rac{-}{t}{t}[1]i{-}{o}{o}[2]n}
\begin{document}
\hspace*{29.4em}abstraction
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image: English-example output]

which is also wrong because *i* has been wrongly replaced with *t*.

Who is the culprit and what to do?

plain tex:

```
\hyphenation{Ab{-}{s}{s}{-}{t}{t}rak{-}{t}{t}i{-}{o}{o}ns-ebe{-}{n}{n}e}

X\hskip 400pt Abstraktionsebene

X\hskip 420pt Abstraktionsebene



\bye
```

Comment: As I don't speak German I can't be sure that it does any better, but have you tried `polyglossia` instead of `babel`? It has a couple of options that seem to be relevent to this situation (`spelling=new` and `babelshorthands=true`).

Comment: @Miyase My original example is not minimal but real-life. I added a smaller (not real-life) example that goes without *babel* or *polyglossia*.

Comment: @GeekestGeek a more minimal example not using latex

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61693328#61693328

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an engine level bug in the luatex source (`texlang.c`) Hans is testing a fix
which looks good so far:

[image]

So this will be fixed at source in the next day or so, so in texlive 2023 (probably earlier in miktex) There is no real workaround other than avoid using adjacent instances of the extended brace syntax such as `{-}{s}{s}{-}{t}{t}`

Comment: Thx! As of now (2022-08-02 19:34 UTC), the update is not in (standard) TeX Live. As for TeX Live 2023, would I have to get it from github and build it myself?

Comment: @GeekestGeek yes (or svn for original source). At the point I posted this answer it was not checked in at all, I built after patching based on an email from Hans, but it is checked in now. texlive binaries are not updated mid year so this will not be in texlive until tl 2023

Comment: Thanks! (Frankly, given that I run into other, unrelated issues even with the current TeX Live 2022 (I plan to post about them in short), I'm unsure whether/when I am able to test TL 2023.)

Comment: The first such issue is http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/652792 , just in case you happen to be interested. (As of today, I unfortunately have to switch back to a stock TeX Live from Debian, so as to make some progress with actual typesetting rather than debugging TeX Live. I apologize tremendously.)