# current Tex Live (2022-08-02): svmono + isodate + \maketitle = error

Tags: titles, sv-classes, isodate

Feeding

```
\documentclass{svmono}% v5.10 from http://resource-cms.springernature.com/springer-cms/rest/v1/content/20566/data/monographs .
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}% whether you use babel or not, you get an error.
\usepackage[num,ngerman]{isodate}% USenglish instead of ngerman fails as well.
\begin{document}
\author{Author}
\title{Title}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

to any of `[xe|lua|pdf]latex` spits out the error

```
! Extra \or.
\ifthenelse #1->\toks@ {#1}\TE@repl \or 
                                        \TE@or \TE@repl \and \TE@and \TE@rep...
l.7 \maketitle
```

In this issue, I used the current up-to-date TeX Live:

- pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022)
- LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5
- L3 programming layer <2022-07-15>
- svmono 2021/09/08 v5.10
- babel 2022/07/20 3.78
- isodate 2010/01/03 v2.30

A prior TeX Live from Debian testing (2022) with babel loaded poses no issues at least with `pdflatex`.  However, now you get an error if you drop `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`. The versions used are as follows:

- pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022/Debian)
- LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
- L3 programming layer <2022-06-02>
- svmono 2021/09/08 v5.10
- babel 2022/05/22 3.75
- isodate 2010/01/03 v2.30

The maintainers of `svmono` at SPi (are they the current ones?) and the maintainer of `isonum` (e-mail taken from the documentation of `babelbib`) have been informed.

Who is the culprit and what to do?

Comment: well, svmono tests the date and doesn't like the format of isodate. So basically the two are incompatible. Why do you use such a class and then try to change their date format?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That's not quite the case that the two are incompatible. In Debian testing, they are compatible. Using stock Debian and Ubuntu TeX Live, svmono (in various versions) has been compatible with isodate at least since 2019, if not longer. I'm going to reply to “why” later.

Comment: I get same error in tl 2020, 2021, 2022, do you really get no error in your other system, do you have a local patch perhaps?

Comment: I have Document Class: svmono 2018/06/25 v5.6  though

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It turned out that the presence of babel is relevant for an older TeX Live (without babel, you get an error, and with babel, you don't) and irrelevant for a newer TeX Live (you get an error either with or without babel). While constructing a minimal nonworking example, I used the new TeX Live only, hence commenting babel out. I apologize for confusion. Now I updated the issue report. The version5.6 or svmono is almost the same as 5.10 (a typo has been corrected); it should not matter, I hope.

Comment: `\usepackage[german]{babel}` (which is, I think, the preferred form) works

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's where our results differ. For me, having `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` produces the same error as not having it using current TeX Live I downloaded and installed locally according to https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html .  I adapted the original post accordingly.

Comment: also addig `\makeatletter
\protected\expandafter\def\expandafter\@date\expandafter{\expandafter{\@date}}
\makeatother` at end of preamble works

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Indeed, I confirm this. Thanks for the fix! I hope that some of the maintainers would come up with a permament solution inside their classes or packages.

Comment: imho if svmono wants to check if the date is empty it should better set in a box, instead of using `\if!\@date!` and hoping that the command doesn't contain anything that explodes in such a context.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer see my answer:-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Now let me address your “why” question. These days I use `\usepackage[num,ngerman]{isodate}` only to format the date on the title page the way the author likes it (which is DD. MM. YYYY) and indeed deviates from the default of Springer). In the past, I used `\usepackage[num,USenglish,british,french,german,ngerman]{isodate}` to format the dates in the bibliography using the language of the cited bibliography entry.  Unfortunately, I no longer have the input that shows the difference but could attempt to reconstruct it if you really insist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svmono` does

```
  \if!\@date!\else
    {\large \@date}%          % Date set in \large size.
```

This is an "optimistic" test for `\@date` being empty (ie the document having `\date{}`).

It's hard to enumerate exactly when it will fail, but essentially it will fail if `\@date` is defined to do anything interesting. This is a particularly aggressive form of expansion so an etex `\protected` definition would not help, and a latex `\protect` robust definition would only help in some cases.

`isodate` defines `\@date` to use `\ifthenelse` tests from the `ifthen` package, which is perhaps useful for simple top level tests but extremely fragile and not usable in any kind of code or expansion contexts.

In previous releases this combination produces the error you show by default but if you also added `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` a series of accidental  effects avoided an error by luck rather than design.

Some change in babel has meant the luck ran out and you now get the error with or without babel. I didn't trace what changed as it wouldn't be resonable to expect other packages to keep such a fragile test working.

svmono could use

`\ifx\@date\@empty`

or perhaps

`\if$\detokenize\expadafter{\@date}$`

as below, or they could reasonably claim that as a publisher class they only support date forms used by Springer Journals so supporting other date format packages is out of scope.

```
\makatletter
\def\@maketitle{\newpage
 \null
 \vskip 2em                 % Vertical space above title.
\begingroup
  \def\and{\unskip, }
  \parindent=\z@
  \pretolerance=10000
  \rightskip=\z@ \@plus 3cm
  {\LARGE                   % each author set in \LARGE
   \lineskip .5em
   \@author
   \par}%
  \vskip 2cm                % Vertical space after author.
  {\Huge \@title \par}%     % Title set in \Huge size.
  \vskip 1cm                % Vertical space after title.
  \ifx\@subtitle\@empty\else%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
   {\LARGE\ignorespaces\@subtitle \par}
   \vskip 1cm                % Vertical space after subtitle.
  \fi
  \ifx\@date\@empty\else %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    {\large \@date}%          % Date set in \large size.
    \par
    \vskip 1.5em               % Vertical space after date.
  \fi
 \vfill
 {\Large Springer Nature\par}
%\vskip 5\p@
%\large
%  Berlin\enspace Heidelberg\enspace New\kern0.1em York\\
%  Hong\thinspace Kong\enspace London\\
%  Milan\enspace Paris\enspace Tokyo\par
\endgroup}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks! For me, the patch works like a charm for both Debian-testing TeX Live and TeX Live from CTAN.